# What kind of object is returned by Coinbase's client.get_primary_account method?

Tags: ruby, api, coinbase-api

I'm using the Ruby API for Coinbase.  I'm trying to mock the below call

```
account = @client.get_primary_account()
```

in which "@client' is built using

```
@client = Coinbase::Wallet::Client.new(api_key: ENV['COINBASE_KEY'],
                                  api_secret: ENV['COINBASE_SECRET'],
                                  CB_VERSION: 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

However, I can't find an API reference for the "get_primary_account" method, which I assume would tell me what kind of object "account" is.

Comment: it looks like its just json data

Comment: well I am going to have to assume this is a [`Coinbase::Wallet::Account`](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby/blob/master/lib/coinbase/wallet/models/account.rb) but you can confirm by simply calling `account.class` annnnd it appears i would be Correct [Source](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby/blob/master/lib/coinbase/wallet/api_client.rb#L140)

Comment: ^ This. I'm not sure why you're asking us -- can't you just look at the variable and see for yourself?

Comment: I'm writing a unit test in which I'm trying to mock the behavior, so I need to know what class I should mock.